# cx_freeze import error scipy.__config__

Tags: tkinter, scipy, scikit-learn, python-3.4, cx-freeze

made tkinter GUI and convert exefile.
so used cx_freeze and made setup code

```
import cx_Freeze import sys import pandas as pd import pickle from sklearn import preprocessing import numpy as np

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
base = "Win32GUI" 

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("150921_cdGUI_tkint.py", base=base, )]

cx_Freeze.setup(
name = "150921_cdGUI_tkint",
option = {"build_exe": {"packages":
["tkinter","sklearn","pandas","numpy","pickle"]}},
version = "0.1",
description = "150921_cdGUI_tkint",
executables = executables)
```

and run exe file this error message

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
...
ImportError: No module named 'scipy.__config__'
...
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing scipy: you cannot import scipy while being in scipy source directory; Please exit the scipy source tree first, and relaunch your python interpreter
```

And in the GUI code, input the  **"from sklearn import preprocessing"** 
this line deleted, and made exe file didn't error.......;;;
I don't know what to do...
AQAP Help

```
"use version"
Anaconda(spyder python3.4 65bit)
cx_Freeze-4.3.4
pandas 0.16.2
numpy 1.9.3
scipy-0.16.0
scikit_learn-0.16.1
sklearn
```